# Multiple networks in same project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to understand networks and subnets in GCP. If I create multiple auto mode networks in the same project, what happens exactly?

Seems if I create multiple VMs in same network, they can connect to each other no matter which region/zone they belong to.

But if I create one VM in network 1 and another in network2, they cannot connect to each other. And they have the same internal IP. So is this means that they cannot connect to each other?

So why should one need multiple networks in one project? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of a VPC as a virtual version of your traditional physical network. VPCs are global, spanning all regions. The instances within the VPC have internal IP addresses and can communicate privately with each other across the globe. This logical representation of your network infrastructure abstracts much of the complexities of dealing with on-premises architectures.

Auto mode networks create one subnet in each GCP region automatically when you create the network. As new regions become available, new subnets in those regions are automatically added to the auto mode network. IP ranges for the automatically created subnets come from a predetermined set of ranges.
On the other hand, Custom mode networks start with no subnets, giving you full control over subnet creation and IP addressing.

If you create multiple auto mode VPC networks in your project, each VPC network will be spread across all the available zones and regions, and instances in each VPC network will communicate between each other, but both VPC networks will not communicate unless you configure a link between them ( VPC peering, Cloud VPN tunnel )

If you have two auto mode networks, both will use the same network IP ranges configured in the same regions, so if you create an instance in each VPC in the same region you will have two instances with the same internal IP address. But bear in mind that those instances could also have external IP addresses configured, so they could be able to communicate through their public IP addresses as long as the VPC firewall of the destination instance allows the ingress traffic.

If two VPC networks use the same IP address ranges, that is to say that they have overlapping IP ranges , you cannot link them because the routing will not be feasible between both VPC networks.

Note that you can configure an instance to have multiple network interfaces, each in different VPC networks, thus enabling the instance to communicate with both different worlds.

There are plenty of reasons why you could need multiple VPC networks in one project, especially because they are both segregated and not able to communicate between each other.
If you want to interconnect VPC networks (being in the same project or not) you can use custom mode VPC networks and link them via VPC peering or VPN tunnels as long as their IP ranges do not match.

You will find extensive information on GCP public doc on VPC networking at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc).